# How to URL encode JSF outputLink value

Tags: java, jsf, urlencode

I've got some code that looks similar to this:

```
<h:outputLink value="#{bean.url}" />
```

But the output contains an apostrophe in the link href which is *not* URL encoded.

Am I doing something wrong or is this normal behaviour for outputLink? Thanks in advance.

(JBoss 4.2, Java 1.6)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It indeed won't do that for you. It will at highest append the `jsessionid` for the case the client doesn't support cookies. Only the link parameters which are added using `<f:param>` will be URL-encoded.

```
<h:outputLink value="#{bean.url}">Click
    <f:param name="param1" value="#{bean.urlParam1}" />
    <f:param name="param2" value="#{bean.urlParam2}" />
</h:outputLink>
```

Comment: Not all parameters are encoded in the Query part of the URL. `<f:param>` only takes care of adding and encoding parameters in the Query part. Hence there might be a need to url encode portions of the `value` attribute in <h:outputLink> as well.

Comment: @YoYo: As answered, h:outputLink won't do that for you. Just split them out so they can be specified via f:param.

Comment: Url is something like `#{base}/request;par1=val1/detail?par2=val2`. I do not understand how I can 'split' so I can supply par1 as `<f:param>`? No problem for `par2` though ... My solution would be to manually encode par2 and directly inject in the `<h:outputLink>` `value` attribute. You seem to suggest something simpler?